# How to Convert Bitmap type to String type

Tags: android, string, sqlite, bitmap, get

In model class i initialized bitmap type for image.Now i'm implementing sqlite for data storage.I initialized string type for image in table column.Getting bitmap error when i'm trying to get the details by using column_id using cursor.

My class is  :

```
public class ContactsModel {
    public static final String Table_Name="Contacts";

    public static final String Column_Name="Names";
    public static final String Column_Number="Numbers";
    public static final String Column_Photo="Images";
    public static  final String Column_id="Id";

    private String Name;
    private String Number;
    private Bitmap Image;
    private int Id;

    public String Create_Table= "CREATE TABLE" + Table_Name +"("+Column_id+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" + Column_Name + " TEXT," + Column_Number + " TEXT," + Column_Photo + " BLOB)";
    public ContactsModel(int id,String name,String number,Bitmap image){

        this.Id=id;
        this.Name=name;
        this.Number=number;
        this.Image=image;
    }
}
```

And get Method in SqliteOpenHelper class is  :

```
public ContactsModel getContact(long id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.query(ContactsModel.Table_Name,new String[]{ContactsModel.Column_Name,ContactsModel.Column_Number,ContactsModel.Column_Photo},ContactsModel.Column_id +"=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    ContactsModel model=new ContactsModel(
            cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.Column_id)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.Column_Name)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.Column_Number)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.Column_Photo)));

    cursor.close();
    return model;
}
```

Error is getting in the method when trying to get the image by using cursor because of data type.Please help me.

Comment: Instead of storing bitmap in database simple save string file path or image name.

Comment: Why are you storing bitmap i don't know. It's not recommend way to store bitmap. Instead you can save image path or image name as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Convert Bitmap to String :

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
 byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
 String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
 return temp;
```

}

Convert String to Bitmap :

```
public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString) {
try {
    byte[] encodeByte = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0,
            encodeByte.length);
    return bitmap;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getMessage();
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: where i have to convert from bitmap to string in my code

Comment: @Priyanka At the place where you inserting the data in database, just convert the bitmap into string and save it in form of string in your sql database. And at time of getting the data for a id convert that string into bitmap.

Comment: i converted from bitmap to string.Now i'm getting error.i.e.,CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it will help you.

```
public ContactsModel getContact(long id){
SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor=db.query(ContactsModel.Table_Name,new String[]{ContactsModel.Column_Name,ContactsModel.Column_Number,ContactsModel.Column_Photo},ContactsModel.Column_id +"=?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
if(cursor!=null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.Column_Photo)), Base64.DEFAULT);
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0,
        encodeByte.length);
ContactsModel model=new ContactsModel(
        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.Column_id)),
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.Column_Name)),
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsModel.Column_Number)),
        bitmap);

   cursor.close();
   return model;
}


}
```

Comment: "Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0 " error is getting at byte[] line and app going to crash

Comment: You need to check cursor is null or not, let me edit my code

Comment: Is your database contain ContactsModel.Column_Photo column?

Comment: No.It's not Working.Still same issue persisting

Comment: Please check the below query once.Let me know if any mistake is there.

Comment: public static  final String Create_Table = "CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name +" ("+Column_id+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + Column_Name + " TEXT," + Column_Number + " TEXT," + Column_Photo + " BLOB)";

Comment: why you can't use SQLite browser for making database.